# mongodb project element to a C# array property

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following model in C#:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [BsonElement("a")]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("b")]
    public string[] B { get; set; }

    // more fields
    ....
}
```

I would like to project this model from MongoDB to a lightweight class only with fields I am interested in:

```
var result = Collection.Find(FilterDefinition<MyModel>.Empty)
                       .Project(Builders<MyModel>.Projection
                                                 .Include("a")
                                                 .Include("b"))
                       .ToList();
```

The above code seems to return the result as a `List<BsonDocument>`.
So I have the following code to map it to `MyModel`:

```
var myModels = from m in result
               select new MyModel
               {
                   A = m["a"].AsString,
                   B = m["b"].AsBsonArray
               };
```

But the `AsBsonArray` is an array of `BsonValue`, seemingly. So the question is how can I convert it to a `string[]`?